# Differential equation which has following solution $y=\frac{1}{1+\exp(ax)}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Is there any linear differential equation which has following solution 
$$y=\frac{1}{1+\exp(ax)}$$
$a$ is constant.
something like:
$$ y'' + by' +cy + \alpha = 0$$
where $b$, $\alpha$ and $c$ are constants.
When I take derivative it looks more and more complicated.

---

Update: If not possible, What if the coefficients ($b$ and $c$) can be like:
$$ b = b_0 y, \; c = c_0 y + d_0 $$

Comment: I recommend writing $y$ in terms of hyperbolic functions.

Comment: I don't understand your update. Can you clarify your post?

Comment: I mean b and c can y times a coefficient so it becomes nonlinear ODE

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, then my present answer has a first-order example of such. To get a higher-order case, start with a higher derivative of $y$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, I updated what I mean. The equation I am looking for is like the one mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $z:=y^{-1}-1=e^{a x}$ satisfies $z''=az'=a^2 z$. From this we observe that $$y'=-z'(1+z)^{-2}=-a z y^2=-a(y-y^2)\implies y'+a(1-y)y=0.$$ This is a *nonlinear* first-order ODE, which is separable and so can be integrated to obtain 
$y(x)=(1+C e^{a x})^{-1}.$ For $C=1$ this reproduces the given solution, but note that this solution is nonlinear in $C$.

From this nonlinear ODE we can create another:
$$y''=\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[-a (y-y^2)\right]=-a (1-2y)y'\\\implies 
y''+a(1-2y)y'=0\\
\implies y''-2ayy'-a^2 (1-y)y=0$$

So now we have a second-order nonlinear ODE, but whose *coefficients* are linear in $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Not a constant-coefficient homogeneous linear differential equation.  The Laplace transform of the solution of a constant-coefficient de is a rational function.
This function's Laplace transform is not rational (it has infinitely many poles).

Answer (score 2):

You want the *logistic equation*: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticEquation.html), [William Stein's writeup](http://wstein.org/edu/winter06/20b/notes/html/node59.html). Caveat: this is  a nonlinear equation.

Answer (score 0):

Only for completeness (and for playing around).

You can show that the following (false) 2nd order linear ODE:

$$ y'' + a \tanh{\frac{a x}{2} } \, y' = 0, \quad y=y(x),$$ has $1/(1+e^{ax})$ as a solution (the other one is $1/(1+e^{-ax})$!).

**Hint**: you may want to work out on the definition of $\tanh$, particularly in the case of double/half angles.